# Can we read and write multiple types of objects from a text file in JAVA using binary file writing and reading?

Tags: java, oop

If we have two object types,
Car car  = new Car();
Van van = new Van();

Can we write car object and van object to a txt file using binary file writing and read the txt file again to load the data. Using ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean - if you use `ObjectOutputStream` then it *won't* be a text file. Those are for *binary* data. What were you expecting to see in the text file?

Comment: It's called Serialization. Read here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/